# How does Global.asax PostAuthenticateRequest event binding happen?

Tags: asp.net, .net, events, global-asax, autoeventwireup

How can I use the **PostAuthenticateRequest** event of Global.asax? I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/forms-authentication-configuration-and-advanced-topics-cs) and it mentions that I have to use the **PostAuthenticateRequest** event. When I added the Global.asax event it created two files, the markup and the code-behind file. Here is the content of the code-behind file

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace authentication
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {    
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }

        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I type the

```
protected void Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

It is successfully called. Now I want to know how is the **PostAuthenticateRequest** bound to this **Application_OnPostAuthenticateRequest** method? How can I change the method to some other?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Magic..., a mechanism called *Auto Event Wireup*, the same reason you can write

```
Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
}
```

in your code-behind and the method will automatically be called when the page loads.

[MSDN description for `System.Web.Configuration.PagesSection.AutoEventWireup` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.autoeventwireup.aspx):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether events for ASP.NET pages are automatically connected to event-handling functions.

When `AutoEventWireup` is `true`, handlers are automatically bound to events at run time based on their name and signature. For each event, ASP.NET searches for a method that is named according to the pattern `Page_eventname()`, such as `Page_Load()` or `Page_Init()`. ASP.NET first looks for an overload that has the typical event-handler signature (that is, it specifies `Object` and `EventArgs` parameters). If an event handler with this signature is not found, ASP.NET looks for an overload that has no parameters. More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2059139/57428).

If you wanted to do it explicitly you would write the following instead

```
public override void Init()
{
    this.PostAuthenticateRequest +=
        new EventHandler(MyOnPostAuthenticateRequestHandler);
    base.Init();
}

private void MyOnPostAuthenticateRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: I wasted an hour because it wasn't showing up in Intellisense and I thought I might have to subscribe to the event somehow. Was about to post asking how to implement the event but then I thought let's give it a try and see if I get any errors and voila! it worked :) Thanks anyways

Comment: beware that ie. Application_Start or Session_Start can ONLY be handled through the Auto Event Wireup mechanism, there are no explicit events for them on the HttpApplication class that you can subscribe to.

Comment: Behind the scenes, the event is hooked up by [HttpApplicationFactory.ReflectOnMethodInfoIfItLooksLikeEventHandler](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.web/HttpApplicationFactory.cs,b0a90d9df37ace19).