# Are there really two different versions of HttpApplication? And where's the complete docs for the other one?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Are there two different versions of the class `HttpApplication`, one with an Application_Start method and the other without?  I've found thorough Microsoft documentation for one in System.Web that lacks this method.  This seems to be in the .Net Framework.  The documentation for the other, if other it is, is scattered about and is less thorough.  That version seems to be in ASP.NET.

I'm rather weak on Microsoft and the Web and trying to make sense of an existing product that doesn't quite work.  If there *are* two versions, where can I find docs on the ASP.Net/Application_Start version like the standard MS docs I'm finding for the .Net Framework version?  (I've found some tutorials, but I'd like a reference.)

Any other clarifications on this subject would be appreciated, though I am sure there's a lot that could be said and (after extensive googling) I am also sure I'm the *only* person out here who doesn't already understand this.

Comment: Have you looked at this SO post... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2058621/difference-between-application-start-and-application-onstart

Comment: @Lloyd: Many thanks!  I did glance at it, along with hundreds of others, but didn't realize it was relevant to my problem.  It does explain another question I had:  why don't these methods need the "override" keyword?